# Can't use a installed package in R

Tags: r, package

I have installed a package in R (ggmap), but when I try to use it R gives an error:

```
> library()

... (all the rest)
gdata                   Various R programming tools for data
                        manipulation
ggmap                   A package for spatial visualization with Google
                        Maps and OpenStreetMap
ggplot2                 An implementation of the Grammar of Graphics
...

> library("ggmap")
Error in FUN(structure(c("write_png", "read_png"), .Names = c("write_png",  : 
  no such symbol write_png in package/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.0/Resources/library/png/libs/png.so
Error: package or namespace load failed for 'ggmap'
```

Any suggestion? Thanks!

PD:

> sessionInfo()

```
R version 3.0.1 (2013-05-16)
Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin10.8.0 (64-bit)

locale:
[1] C

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base
```

EDIT, solution:

Delete `~/Applications/R.app` and `Library/Frameworks/R.framework` and install R again.

Comment: Have you tried reinstalling?

Comment: Yes, but it fails again. Same error.

Comment: Have you tried updating all of your packages? `update.packages()`

Comment: Try reinstalling R. That library comes with the standard R installation, so it is either corrupt or not being referenced correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Could in be that you have another R installation for an earlier version 3.0 vs the 3.0.1 showing in your sessionInfo()?

> Error in FUN(structure(c("write_png", "read_png"), .Names =
>   c("write_png",  :    no such symbol write_png in
>   package/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.0/Resources/library/png/libs/png.so
>   Error: package or namespace load failed for 'ggmap'

Comment: Solved. I have installed R again after deleting the R.framework folder and it works. Thanks to all!

Answer (score 0):

Go to the RStudio-->Options-->Global-->'General'-->R Version
Change the R Version to the latest one which you want to use.